# How can i set trimbox with jsPdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I m using the jsPdf library in order to create pdf files for print production. Is there a way to set the trimbox of the file?

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2152

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I have read this post but there is no getCurrentPageInfo() in the latest version of jspdf

Comment: What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: It is mentioned to the post that you sent me

Comment: The post I sent you is a bug tracking issue that indicates jsPdf does not yet support the feature you want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found official API but it's possible to set the raw values (in pt)!

sample with jsPDF 2.0.0:

```js
const doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'mm', format: [10, 10] });
const page = doc.getCurrentPageInfo();
const scale = 72 / 25.4; // convert mm to pt (boxes use use pt)
page.pageContext.bleedBox = {
            bottomLeftX: 2 * scale,
            bottomLeftY: 2 * scale,
            topRightX:   8 * scale,
            topRightY:   8 * scale
};

page.pageContext.trimBox = { ... };
page.pageContext.artBox = { ... };
```

see: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/commit/d3e1dbabebca375910a64e2bd5289260146e4aa0